# ReadableNativeArray.getString ClassCastException React Native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I am getting this crash report in play store report. I can't figure it out. It is happening since I implemented `react-native-linear-gradient`

Android Version 9 and 10

Crash Report:
[image: Crash Report]